# Display UITableView's section title when index is touched

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm writing a dictionary app to study iOS and I've implemented a `UITableView` with the alphabet as section titles and an index of all the letters on the right side. It works perfectly, but is it possible for me to display the selected index in a box at the center of the screen? I'm looking at the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) reference but can't see any methods I might override. Help?

Comment: There are no such method available. Please check this apple sample [code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) in this they create custom section and manage click on it.

Comment: Lies. There is such a callback. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to manually create a `UIView` that you put above the `UITableView` which then shows the letter or whatever you want to present. Make sure not to add it to the table view itself as it's a `UIScrollView` subclass and your view would be affected by its `contentOffset`.

When the user presses one index or moves his finger above it, this callback gets called:

```
-tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:
```

Use it to change your view's contents and make it visible and set a timer for it to fade out again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom view that display when you click on the cell and in that view you can add Label to show the alphabet which you have selected.

And yes also if you want to display it on center of your screen than give its X and Y coordinates value according to it.hope it helps...